# Trying to loop through JSON data in my javascript (ASP.Net)

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, underscore.js

I have a javascript function called `getRoute` which is supposed to take a list of `route` objects from my MVC controller and insert them into a dropdown menu in my view.

Here is the function:

```
function getRoute(selectedPart) {
    var $form = $('#form-create'),
        $routeDropdown = $('#dd-route'),
        structure = _.template($('#tmpl-route-list').html());

    if (selectedPart) {
        $form.block();
        $.get('@Url.Action("getRouteFromPart", "wip")', {
            partId: selectedPart
        }).done(function (response) {
            $form.unblock();

            var html = structure({ routes: response });
            $routeDropdown.html(html);
        });
    } else {
        $routeDropdown.html(structure({ routes: null }));
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

`selectedPart` is a value from a different dropdown (not shown here). Based on what is chosen there, `getRoute` will hit the `"wip"` controller and use its "`getRouteFromPart"` action to bring back a list of route objects called `routes`. Then it is supposed to put that list into the dropdown menu via an underscore.js template called `#tmpl-route-list`.

Here's that template code:

```
<% if (routes) { %>
    <% foreach(var route in routes.routes) { %>
        <option value="<%= route.routesId %>">
            <% route.routesName %>
        </option>
    <% } % >
<% } %>
```

**Explanation**

`routes.routes` refers to the *routes* list inside the *routes* response object. I'm trying to loop through that list and put the `routeId` and `routeName` of each `route` object into its own `<option>` tag for the dropdown.

Needless to say, it doesn't work. In the javascript console it gives me the error "Unexpected token var". If I remove 'var' from the foreach, it says "Unexpected token {".

Note: I have almost the exact same setup in another part of the website and it works perfectly. The only difference is *there* it gets just a single object to put in the dropdown and *here* I'm trying to do it with a list of objects. Clearly there is something wrong with my looping or something, but I don't know how to fix it.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your templating looks all wrong.
Where is the call to `_.forEach`? Where is the callback?

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/ub25v2c6/1/ (Open the console).

I changed the template to the snippet below and it compiles fine.

```
var template = `
    <% if (routes) { %>
      <% _.forEach(routes.routes, function (route, i) { %>
          <option value="<%= route.routesId %>">
              <% route.routesName %>
          </option>
      <% }); %>
  <% } %>
`;
```